# 500 Error on a Django page that uses Ajax

Tags: python, django

I'm having a 500 error after trying to submit a csv file. The 500 error says having a problem in DeproAjaxView. Up until November this was working fine.

Now the live site is giving the 500 error, but the local development server is giving a 403 forbidden error (csrf token missing or incorrect). I checked that, and it does have a token.

```
class DeprovisionView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = "technology/deprovision.html"
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def test_func(self):
        user = self.request.user.id
        groups = User.objects.filter(pk=user,groups__name__exact='HARDWARE_ADMIN').exists()
        return groups

class DeproAjaxView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,View):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def test_func(self):
        user = self.request.user.id
        groups = User.objects.filter(pk=user,groups__name__exact='HARDWARE_ADMIN').exists()
        return groups

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        device_list = defaultdict(list)
        error_list = []
        success_list = []
        devices = []
        deprovision = []
        csv_data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
        data = list(chain.from_iterable(csv_data.get('data')))

        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        response = sorted(loop.run_until_complete(async_get_chromebook(data, loop)),
                key=itemgetter('status'))

        for item in response:
            device_list[item['status']].append(item)

        for key, value in device_list.items():
            if key == 'ACTIVE':
                devices.extend(value)
            else:
                error_list.extend(value)

        if not devices:
            data = {'status': 'error','error_list': error_list}
        else:
            for item in devices:
                deprovision.append(item.get('deviceId')) 

            depro_resp = loop.run_until_complete(async_deprovision(deprovision, loop)) 

            for item in depro_resp:
                if item['status'] == 'SUCCESS':
                    success_list.append(item)
                else:
                    error_list.append(item)

            data = {'status': 'success', 'success_list': success_list, 'error_list': error_list}

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
```

I'm not sure why they raise exceptions. 
Tracebacks:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/annisasamsi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.88468/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/Users/annisasamsi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.88468/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "/Users/annisasamsi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.88468/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/annisasamsi/Projects/iron/apps/technology/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Looking deeper Chrome's error log says

```
XHR failed loading: POST "https://irondistrict.org/technology/ajax/depro/".
send    @   vendor.d456b52….js:128
ajax    @   vendor.d456b52….js:128
complete    @   technology.d456b52….js:1
parseChunk  @   vendor.d456b52….js:89
_chunkLoaded    @   vendor.d456b52….js:89
(anonymous) @   vendor.d456b52….js:89
load (async)        
stream  @   vendor.d456b52….js:89
parse   @   vendor.d456b52….js:89
(anonymous) @   technology.d456b52….js:1
dispatch    @   vendor.d456b52….js:128
g.handle    @   vendor.d456b52….js:128
```

I've also tried using decorators, but those make it so the entire site won't load.

Comment: Please add the tracebacks too.

Comment: `No module named 'requests'`, have you installed this module? Try `pip install requests`.

Comment: I do have the module named requests in my requirements.txt (requests==2.18.4)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some missing libraries in your code. Probably [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/).

Do a `pip install requests` and it should work.

Also a side note, when you have your project up and running, use this command to store all of your project dependencies in a singular file so that if you or someone else has cloned a fresh copy of the project they don't have to manually install the dependencies.

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

To install the list of requirements.txt you can use

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: I did try `pip install requests` but that told me that the `Requirement already satisfied`

Answer (score 0):

"/Users/annisasamsi/Projects/iron/apps/technology/views.py", **line 2**, in 
    import requests

Line 2: it seems that it's the first module your code is trying to import and it can't find it. I suppose that the samething  will happen with other modules.

Plz be sure that you run **pip install -r requirements.txt** in right envirement. And check your projecte **sites-packages**